# Shortcut to "New Branch" popup in IntelliJ

Tags: git, intellij-idea, keyboard-shortcuts

I'd like to setup keyboard shortcut to create new Git branch in IntelliJ IDEA.

I've tried assigning shortcut to the following action:

[image]

However, at least in IDEA 2016.3, this action doesn't perform anything when invoked.

How can I setup shortcut to just open this popup?

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I just tried this in `2016.3` as well, did not work for me either (on OSX) so probably a bug in the git integration plugin. <strike>Something to search for in YouTrack.</strike> Created bug **[IDEA-164512](https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/IDEA-164512)**.

However, an alternative is to setup a shortcut for the parent popup `Branches...` , that does work, followed by <kbd>Enter</kbd> :

[image]

So in the absence of the one-fell-swoop shortcut for new branches, a workaround would look as follows:

[image]

Comment: Update as of July '19:

I guess by now you can do it via Ctrl+Shift+` out of the box